# How to covert AM/PM time format to hour format in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, datetime-conversion

I have time like this '2:00 PM' and I want to get it like this '14:00'.Can anyone please help me.Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change format in the component part and not in the view you can use the datepipe as follow:

```
// import the datepipe
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

// init DatePipe
constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {}

// use it like
this.datePipe.transform(myDate, 'HH:mm');
```

An other options would be to use for example angular2-moment (https://github.com/urish/angular2-moment/).

Answer (score 1):

You can format the date using a pipe (`|`) and `date:"<format>"`.

AM / PM is represented as `tt` in date formats.

```
{{time | date:"hh:mm tt"}}
```

So you can remove the AM / PM like this:

```
{{time | date:"hh:mm"}}
```

Comment: Hi Koby Douek,I dont want to display it but need to send that format into db.

Comment: Share your code pleas so I can see where's the problem